# Out Of Memory on String and StringBuilder

Tags: .net, string, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I wrote the code below with StringBuilder first and hit the Out Of Memory Exception, read the related questions and changed it to string += but still receiving the same OOM error.

I have ~2100+ files with different sizes and total of ~200MB+.

Due to the restrictions I can not use append mode file access. Any sugessions?

```
const string myPath = @"C:\values\";

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath).Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension);
var filesGrouped = files.Where(f => f.Length > 12).GroupBy(f => f.Substring(0, f.Length - 9)).OrderBy(f => f.Key).ToList();

filesGrouped.ForEach(fg =>
    {
        var myRows = string.Empty;

        // download files
        fg.ToList().ForEach(gf =>
            {
                string myFile;
                string fileToRead = string.Format("{0}{1}.csv", myPath, gf);
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileToRead)) myFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
                //! OOM Error hits the line below
                myRows += myFile + ControlChars.NewLine;
            });

        // upload new file
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(myPath + fg.Key + ".csv", false, Encoding.UTF8)) sw.Write(myRows);
    });
```

Comment: Sidenote: replace `ControlChars.NewLine` with `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
filesGrouped.ForEach(fg =>
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(myPath + fg.Key + ".csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        fg.ToList().ForEach(gf =>
        {
            string fileToRead = string.Format("{0}{1}.csv", myPath, gf);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileToRead))
            {
                foreach (var line in sr.ReadLine())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
                sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

If that also fails (the file content is on a single line), you have to option to use the same principle, [StreamReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.read.aspx) in conjunction with [StreamWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx).

Comment: thank you! it did work with a minor fix.  Thank you for your time and attention!

Comment: by the way I tried to edit the code but looks like not updated. in order to make the above code work replace the inside of **using (var sr = ...)** with **while (!sr.EndOfStream) sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());**